# Is it safe to format this extended partition?

Tags: linux, partition

On a ubuntu server I own, I am running out of space. When I ran

```
sudo parted /dev/sda -l
```

to find all available drives, I got this:

```
Model: ATA ST31000528AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
 5      257MB   1000GB  1000GB  logical                lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/server--vg-swap_1: 2135MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  2135MB  2135MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/server--vg-root: 998GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  998GB  998GB  ext4
```

I understand /dev/mapper/server--vg-root is the filesystem, and /dev/sda1 has some stuff related to GRUB.

But, what about /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda5? When I tried to mount /dev/sda2, it said that I needed to specify the file system, which according to the table, is nonexistent. So, is it safe to format this with, say ext4 and mount it?

Also, when I tried to mount /dev/sd5, it gave me this error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

I assume it is NOT save to reformat this. If I'm wrong, then that would be great, because I could save some space. Please let me know either way. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Here is the result of `mount`:

```
/dev/mapper/server--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,acl)
/dev/sda1 on /media/hd2 type ext2 (rw)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No!

`/dev/sda` contains:

- a small `/dev/sda1` which is needed to boot.
- a extended partition `/dev/sda2`

The extended partition contains a logical partition `/dev/sda5`.

The logical partition contains a LVM setup, broken down into to two logical volumes:

- `/dev/mapper/server--vg-swap_1` which is your swap space
- `/dev/mapper/server--vg-root` which is your root (`/`) partition where everything is stored.

There is nothing there that is unused, so the bottom line is you are out of space.

You will need to add additional storage to the system.  Luckily, you have LVM so you can add it to the volume group and simply expand the logical volume `server--vg-root` and then the filesystem within it.

Answer (score 1):

sda2 is kind of like a 'suitcase' holding all extended partitions. You can't delete it. sda5 is the only partition in the 'suitcase', and is your LVM physical volumes. You can't delete it.

To actually see what you have spare space wise, use these commands:

`df -h` : Shows the free space on all your volumes (you might be able to reclaim some space)

`vgs` : Shows all your volume groups, and VFree is the free space (possibly none)

`lvs` : Shows all your volumes (in case you have an unused volume you can delete)